# Chrome Extension PopUp closed and stopped working, When moving to next tab

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

Just Using the Extension to parse data in that current Page.

when i click the Extension Icon, it will show a popup and in that its getting the data.

But, when i click that Popup and switch to next tab or window. Popup window gets stopped and Not working.

Want to work with that popup in every tab simultaneously, So Can anyone Help to get Solution for this scenario.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the parsed data?  Why do you need the popup?  Can't you just have the one popup take in whatever information you need (what does your popup need to do?) and then do something (whatever that is) in every open tab?

Answer (score 0):

That's by design, popup will dismiss when it lost focus.

And from your description, if you "Just Using the Extension to parse data in that current Page.", you could listen to `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` event and choose to use `chrome.tabs.create({url: "popup.html"});` to open a tab instead.

Comment: i want to get the content of attached file in that page. there only extension gets slow. Im using XmlHttpRequest to get content, Can yu plz tell me better way to get content quickly.

Comment: @DhilipKumarC, attached file in that page, what do you mean?